# Cannot Load Images from Jar

Tags: java, image, swing, jar, embedded-resource

I'm making a simple game in Java, and trying to load a sprite from the jar file. I'm using the following code to load a sprite:

```
spriteURL = getClass().getResource("/res/sprites/sprite_fr1.png");
```

And if I export a jar file and unzip it, the following folders exist:

> /res/sprites/sprite_fr1.png

However, when I try and load the image, I catch a NullPointerException, even though, as far as I can tell, the path exists?

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Screenshot below.

[image: Folder Structure]

All sprites are in the folder 'sprites' as PNG files. I'm calling the method from jeu, not jeu/canvases.

Regards,
Ben.

Comment: Make sure of the case of the packages/filename is correct i.e capital letters where necessary. Windows is not case sensitive however java is.

Comment: No capitals in any file names - do I need to include the package name in the getResource() method? Even if the res/ folder is in the top directory of the jar?

Comment: Try to: `spriteURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(PATH);`

Comment: @BenMagee If *res* is within another package yes.

Comment: No such luck with `spriteURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/res/sprites/sprite_fr1.png");`, Maroun. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp - res isn't in any package. Does this affect anything?

Comment: @BenMagee No not as far as I know. Please take a screenshot of your package structure and post it so we can see how your jar file is structured

Comment: @BenMagee I saw this as an answer for similar question: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(PATH));`

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Your suggestion still results in a null pointer exception.

Comment: @BenMagee If you're sure that classloader uses this specific jar, then I'm clueless. (It might be that your classloader using files from somewhere else and not this jar)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Screenshot posted.

Comment: Fixed by looking at Deniz's suggestion of build path. sprites/ was excluded from the build path, and even though the png's were still appearing in the jar java didn't seem to be able to find them. Fixed now. Thanks for everybody's help!

Comment: @BenMagee : Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check classpath of your project in your IDE. For example in eclipse there is configuration for each folder (Properties->JAva Build Path->Source Tab). It may be set to exclude png files.

Comment: Hi Deniz, I can see the png's in the jar file though, under the directory specified. It also doesn't work if I run debug from eclipse.